# Class Inheritance issue for ES 6 JS and Its failing tests

Tags: javascript, inheritance, es6-class

I'm a new dev coming from a Ruby background. Recently I've been working very hard in JS and I'm having some issues with class inheritance in the new ES 6. I feel like it may be an issue with my understanding of JS or conflating it to much to Ruby. I've been trying to translate a Ruby Project into JS to practice, but I'm now failing a feature test.

[Failing Feature test when trying to initialize two instances of a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgbtu.png)

```js
const STATS = { str:1, dex:1, int:1 }

class Example {
  constructor(race, clas) {
    this.race = race,
    this.clas = clas,
    this.stats = this.add(STATS)
  }
  
  add(stats) {
    if(this.race != 'empty'){
      stats.str += this.race.str
      stats.dex += this.race.dex
      stats.int += this.race.int
    }
    if(this.clas != 'empty') {
      stats.str += this.clas.str
      stats.dex += this.clas.dex
      stats.int += this.clas.int
    } 
    return stats
  }
}

var a = new Example({str: 1, dex:0, int:0}, 'empty');
var b = new Example('empty', {str: 0, dex:0, int:1});

console.log('Should be str:2 dex:1 int:1');
console.log(a.stats); 
console.log('Should be str:1 dex:1 int:2');
console.log(b.stats);
```

My class has functions that change the state when constructed, but the issue is any time a new Class is called it retains the changes from the previous variable. It is only an issue on my feature test as it is the only time that class is called twice.

This is the link to my feature test https://github.com/RyanWolfen7/jsRPG/blob/master/cypress/integration/featureTest/characterFeature_test.js

And this is the class thats failing the tests
https://github.com/RyanWolfen7/jsRPG/blob/master/models/characters/character.js

Honestly I'm probably going to scrap my project and start fresh anyways, but I would like to understand what my issue is. I was taking an OOD approach to JS and translating my ruby project https://github.com/RyanWolfen7/ruby_rpg to JS. I'm not sure if its because I wrote the test wrong or a deep misunderstanding of how es-6 works.

Things I have tried:

Creating a new object

Assigning a newly created object to new class

Comment: Can you embed a minimal code snippet in this question that exactly demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Hey Ryan. Please note that the most important pieces of your question are completely reliant on external resources, which is slightly frowned upon. As @Evert mentioned, if you could edit your question to include a [**minimal, complete, verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be much appreciated.

Comment: useful stuff on JS OO http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html , http://www.crockford.com/javascript/prototypal.html , http://crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, can't find any obvious mistakes.

Comment: Hey guys updated a code snippit and its running into the same error i'm getting. could it be because the constants are outside the class and if so how would i correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an inheritance issue. In fact, it has nothing to do with OO at all. What you are seeing is the result of the fact that most things in javascript are references (pointers) but you are writing code as if `STATS` is a value.

In your function `add` you do this:

```
add(stats) {
  if(this.race != 'empty'){
    // modifying passed in object, not creating new object
    stats.str += this.race.str
    stats.dex += this.race.dex
    stats.int += this.race.int
  }
  if(this.clas != 'empty') {
    // modifying passed in object, not creating new object
    stats.str += this.clas.str
    stats.dex += this.clas.dex
    stats.int += this.clas.int
  } 
  return stats
}
```

So no matter how many times you call `add()` and from whichever instance of `Example` you call it from you are only accessing and overwriting the single shared `STATS` object.

To create new copies of `STATS` on each function call you need to copy it to a new object. The fastest old-school way to do this is to serialise the object to a string then convert the string back to an object:

```
add (input) {
  var stats = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));

  // ...
}
```

This feels ugly but multiple benchmarks really did show it to be the fastest method.

Modern javascript can do this using `Object.assign`:

```
add (input) {
  var stats = Object.assign({},input);

  // ...
}
```

However, I don't know if it is faster. You will have to benchmark it yourself. You can google the phrase **"js clone object"** for more info.